# Closing a Winium from a thread with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, winium

So i'm trying to automate a desktop app using winium and i want to automate the launching of the winium driver thru script, so far i'm able to start it just fine, but when it comes to closing it, that's the problem.

```
winium = Thread.new{
   system (
      File.dirname(__FILE__) 
      +'/Features/Support/support/Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe')
} 
sleep 5 
winium.kill
```

But after i kill the thread, if i check with TCPView i can see that winium is still open, this will cause issues if i try to running the script multiple times without winium closing correctly.. My question is how can i make sure that Winium is stopping after i kill the thread?

i'm working in rubyMine, with ruby 2.4.4 and using the 1.6.0 version of the winium driver.

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html#method-i-kill - says it termintes the thread and schedules another thread to be run?

Comment: I did `a = Thread.new { //some infinite loop }` , then `a.kill`, I got : 
`<Thread:0x00000001542e18@(irb):14 sleep>` , so I retried `a.kill` and got this time `<Thread:0x00000001542e18@(irb):14 dead>`
Maybe you need to kill it twice ?

Comment: I tried and i still see Winium running in TCPView, maybe i have to use socket to close the port and that will do it?

Comment: i found a solution to this, i passed the taskkill ccommand to the console with the image name for winium and did a forceful exec and that does the trick.`system ('taskkill /IM Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe /f')`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, i passed the taskkill command to the console with the image name for winium and did a forceful exec and that does the trick.
`system ('taskkill /IM Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe /f')`